# Load file from Docker container from php file in another container

Tags: php, docker

I'm not sure if this is possible.

I have a container that sets up a php/apache environment to run a small app. That app makes an external database connection but I intend to use that connection in other containers as well.

My thought was to create another container for utilities such as establishing the database connection so that I don't have to manage the connection info in each container.

Using docker-compose I run both containers together but the file with the database connection info in my utilities container isn't readable by the app container.

App `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY /src /var/www/html
COPY /conf /usr/local/lib/php/app-lib/conf
```

Utilities `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

COPY /src /usr/local/lib/php/app-lib/utilities
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  inventory:
    image: repo/inventory:latest
    volumes:
     - ./src:/var/www/html
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - appnet
    depends_on:
      - utilities
  utilities:
    image: repo/utilities:latest
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/lib/php/app-lib/utilities
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 256M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - appnet
networks:
  appnet:
```

PHP file

```
die((file_exists('/usr/local/lib/php/app-lib/utilities/db.php') ? 'exists' : 'not found'));
```

And of course when I hit `http://127.0.0.1` it outputs "not found" so it's not loading the file from the utilities container like that. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this just isn't possible.

I'm converting a monolithic API into services and there are some classes I created to share functions between end points and I'm hoping I can do something similar with the containers so I'm not managing the same code in multiple containers.

Comment: TBH - I would have a copy of the file in each container, it means the container is self contained (which is the principle of using containers) and also it means there isn't a single point of failure (your util container)

Comment: Why don't you create a volume in the same folder for all the containers that will use that specific file?

Comment: Nigel: I was working under the assumption that I'd end up with some large utility functions being used by multiple containers. Having them in each container would make it more cumbersome to maintain. That assumption may be wrong though. I'll reevaluate the original app.

Andre: I'm fairly new to Docker so I'm not familiar with all of the options available. I'll see if I can find a tutorial for that. Chances are I'll reevaulate the app and find that I don't need to share anything.

Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Actually, this looks like a huge overengineering chunk of work. Too me it looks like you want to make things more complex to satisfy your doubts. When you do things as simple as possible, it doesn't always mean you do things bad.

Comment: After looking through the utilities class from my original app it does look like there will not be a lot of overlap between services. So nevermind. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Is it possible that Kubernetes would make the communication I'm aiming for possible without complicating the Docker containers?